# difference in behavior of "tr" command on "dash" (-) between busybox and Ubuntu/Raspbian/etc

Tags: tr, busybox

I have a function in a script which is used to validate that input strings don't contain any unacceptable characters.  In this case, allowable characters are alpha, numeric, underscore, dash, period, and space.

```
#!/bin/sh
pattern="\_\-\. [a-zA-Z0-9]"
while [ 1 ]; do
echo "enter your test string"
read string
echo "result:"
echo "$string" | tr -cd "$pattern" | sed 's/\[//' | sed 's/\]//' 
echo
echo
done
```

Testing on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./trtest.sh 
enter your test string
dash-dash
result:
dash-dash
enter your test string
under_score
result:
under_score
```

Testing on an Onion board (OpenWRT/busybox):

```
root@Omega-FD22:~# ./trtest.sh 
enter your test string
dash-dash
result:
dashdash  <<<----- I'm not expecting this
enter your test string
under_score
result:
under_score
```

So, 
#1 I am not sure why there is a difference in behavior between "tr" in these two cases, specifically on the "dash" character.

#2 If there's another way to do this, I'm open to it.

Thanks for any insights.

DL

Answer (score 1):

FYI one of my diligent colleagues figured it out, so I am passing on his solution.  If you move `"\-"` to the end of the pattern matching string, then it works in both environments.  Somewhat beyond my ability to explain are the technical/philosophical underpinnings of this, but I'm glad it works.

Before:

```
pattern="\_\-\. [a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

After:

```
pattern="\_\. [a-zA-Z0-9]\-"
```

Comment: I believe this is because the `-` is otherwise interpreted as a range. For anyone who finds this and needs to know more specifics, I found [the source](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/tr.c) was unfortunately the best resource available (though whether that's what's deployed in my/your exact situation is hard to tell)